# Enter data in the report dataset

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report

I have to generate a report with reportviewer on visual studio 2017, but when I generate the report I'm shown the error below, I also entered the C # code. I also add screenshots of the XSD and RDLC files. Why do I have this error?

**Screenshot XSD file:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIiTL.jpg

**Screenshot RDLC file:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW2Zf.jpg

**Error:** *A data source has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSetArticoli'*

**C# Code:**

```
public ReportViewer StampaDDT(DDT oggettoDDT, List<Articolo> ListaArticoli)
        {
            try
            {
                //Creazione DataTable Articoli
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Clear();
                dt.TableName = "DataSetArticoli";
                dt.Columns.Add("CodArt");
                dt.Columns.Add("Descrizione");
                dt.Columns.Add("UM");
                dt.Columns.Add("Quantita");

                foreach (var item in ListaArticoli)
                {
                    object[] o = { item.CodiceArticolo, item.Descrizione, item.UM, "" + item.GetQuantita() };
                    dt.Rows.Add(o);
                }
                ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("DataSetArticoli", dt);
                this.r.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
                this.r.LocalReport.Refresh();
                this.r.RefreshReport();
                //Fine DataTable
                this.r.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
                ReportParameterCollection reportParameters = new ReportParameterCollection
                {
                    new ReportParameter("Aspetto",oggettoDDT.GetAspetto() ?? "")
                };

                ReportParameterCollection reportParameters2 = new ReportParameterCollection
                {
                     new ReportParameter("Data",oggettoDDT.GetData() ?? "")
                };

                ReportParameterCollection reportParameters3 = new ReportParameterCollection
                {
                     new ReportParameter("Note",oggettoDDT.GetNote() ?? "")
                };

                ReportParameterCollection reportParameters4 = new ReportParameterCollection
                {
                     new ReportParameter("Trasporto",oggettoDDT.GetTrasporto() ?? "")
                };
                ReportParameterCollection reportParameters5 = new ReportParameterCollection
                {
                     new ReportParameter("Causale",oggettoDDT.GetCausale() ?? "")
                };
                ReportParameterCollection reportParameters6 = new ReportParameterCollection
                {
                     new ReportParameter("Porto",oggettoDDT.GetPorto() ?? "")
                };
                ReportParameterCollection reportParameters7 = new ReportParameterCollection
                {
                     new ReportParameter("Peso",oggettoDDT.GetPeso() ?? "")
                };
                ReportParameterCollection reportParameters8 = new ReportParameterCollection
                {
                     new ReportParameter("Colli",oggettoDDT.GetColli() ?? "")
                };
                ReportParameterCollection reportParameters9 = new ReportParameterCollection
                {
                     new ReportParameter("DescrizioneVettore",oggettoDDT.GetDescrizioneVettore() ?? "")
                };

                this.r.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
                this.r.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters2);
                this.r.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters3);
                this.r.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters4);
                this.r.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters5);
                this.r.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters6);
                this.r.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters7);
                this.r.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters8);
                this.r.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters9);
                this.r.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
                this.r.LocalReport.Refresh();
                this.r.RefreshReport();
                this.r.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Managementerror.SendError("Errore Stampa Risorse Cantiere: " + ex);
            }

            return this.r;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried define the data source for Report Viewer component's datasource from the [Design] instead doing it from code behind (.cs) ? You can actually try it, since I always use that method when I use RDLC.

Goodluck!